# What are the options to invite users to beta test

Tags: android

I used to use TestFlight to track and manage beta users to push android apps to their phones. However, since apple bought TestFlight they have stopped the support for android.

What are some other options I can use? or should I just stick with emailing apk's as an attachment to each beta user...which seems inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Beta testing feature from google developer console. You can publish your apk as beta and can invite your friends to test it, or from the relevant forums to test your app.